# Microsoft Graph API filter Members of Group

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to query the members of a group in Microsoft Azure Active Directory using the Microsoft Graph API. My query works until I try to filter the results. The service throws an exception `Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException` due to an invalid filter clause. I understand that not all Microsoft Graph API endpoints support certain filter clauses. I want to filter the `Members` by name, ideally using the `in` clause. Is this possible? I have tried to use the `startswith` and `in` filter clauses but both throw the same exception.

```
GraphServiceClient client = GetGraphServiceClient(token);
const string graphProperties = "id,givenName,surname,userPrincipalName,jobTitle,department,officeLocation,businessPhones,mobilePhone,mail";
IGroupMembersCollectionWithReferencesRequest query = client.Groups[Settings.IntranetObjectID].Members.Request().Select(graphProperties);
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.SearchText))
{
    query.Filter($"in(displayName, '{model.SearchText}'");
}
IGroupMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage members = await query.Top(PageSize).GetAsync();
model.StaffMembers = new List<StaffMember>();
while (members.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DirectoryObject member in members)
    {
        if (member is User user)
        {
            model.StaffMembers.Add(new StaffMember(user));
        }
    }

    if (members.NextPageRequest == null)
    {
        break;
    }

    members = await members.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
}
```

Comment: 'in' clause is not supported by graph filter query parameters as it is specified in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter) that it supports startswith and any lambda operator. Please share the whole error response with requestid.

Comment: Hey my friend, you are missing a closing bracket: the correct command is query.Filter($"in(displayName, '{model.SearchText}')"); Perhaps this has caused the invalid filter error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v1.0 filter is not supported but if you use beta you would be able to filter with the display name by following few steps.

1. Select the beta endpoint.
2. Add $count=true in the QueryString.
3. Add ConsistencyLevel = eventual to the [Request headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#request-headers).

If you check it in graph explorer you would be able to get it as below.

Query I have Used -

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/aba04a76-ee5e-4e43-a9d6-0d451e1e3e2d/members?$count=true&$select=id,businessPhones,displayName&$filter=displayName eq 'Andrea Simandi (CELA)'
```

[image]

Since you are using SDK you need to use Microsoft.Graph.Beta an, add count() to query and modify headers by adding consistency property in it.

But remember that APIs under the /beta version in Microsoft Graph are subject to change. Use of these APIs in production applications is not supported.

Please go through this [document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/identity/blogs/build-advanced-queries-with-count-filter-search-and-orderby/) for more details.